# `Django administration` to the custom title in project templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

In django admin panel, I have a requirement, how can I change the:
`Django administration` to the custom title?

[image]

I followed a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458265/how-to-change-django-administration-name-to-a-custom-name-in-admin-login-and-a%20), but it do not give the clear steps.

I copy the `django/contrib/admin/templates` to my project `/templates/admin`, and changed the `/templates/admin/base_site.html`:

```
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django11 administration') }}</a></h1>
```

You see, I changed the Django to Django11, but however in the browser, it do not change at all.

The other post on stackoverflow steps are punch-drunk, so who can tell me what should I do more to my requirement? is there need any configurations of my project settings? or something else?

Comment: It’s in the Django beginner’s tutorial... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial07/#Customize%20the%20admin%20look%20and%20feel

Comment: Make sure your browser hasnt cached the text

Comment: @AK47 I use other browser, still this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> No need to copy and change admin template

In project **urls.py** just put

```
admin.site.site_header = 'Mysite Admin Panel'
admin.site.site_title = 'Mysite Admin Panel'
```

> Alternatively:

After copying `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html` put like this

**base_site.html**

```
 {% extends "admin/base.html" %}

 {% block title %}Mysite Admin Panel{% endblock %}

 {% block branding %}
     <h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Mysite Admin Panel</a></h1>
 {% endblock %}

 {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This works, but how can I change it in the project templates?

Comment: and whether copy the admin template works for my requirement? because if this works, I change the admin style or panel will be convenient.

Comment: @244boy, Check now I have update my answer and solved it according to you also. Have a look. It works perfectly now.